# How to format date as real UTC or Unix style in logback logstash encoder?

Tags: logstash, logback, simpledateformat

The timestamp provided by logstash encoder in logback is not in real UTC format even if I specify UTC timezone (instead of Z there's +00:00 at the end of the timestamp)

Comment: As an aside, you don’t want to use `SimpleDateFormat`, it is long outdated. Get in the habit of using the modern Java date and time classes. In this case `Instant` and probably `DateTimeFormatter` (if `Instant.toString()` is not enough).

Comment: Here I&#39;ve no choice because logback logstash lib use SimpleDateFormat. I would prefer to have the choice but I&#39;ve not enough time to change this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that logstash composite encoder is a solution with timestamp provider containing timeZone as UTC and dateFormat as yyyyMMdd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'